# Use Terraform or AZ CLI to configure General Settings for Azure Web Aps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

[image: Web App General Settings]

I create my Web Apps in Azure with the [Azure Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service). I have also looked at [az webapp CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest). But in none of them I can't find the commands to configure the settings under General Settings. Is there a way to use TF or AZ CLI to do that other than the Azure Portal and am I missing it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Azure portal, the General Settings tab groups settings that are set using different switches with **az webapp config**.

For example:

```
--linux-fx-version
```

> The runtime stack used for your linux-based webapp, e.g.,
> "RUBY|2.5.5", "NODE|10.14", "PHP|7.2", "DOTNETCORE|2.1".

```
--net-framework-version
```

> The version used to run your web app if using .NET Framework, e.g.,
> 'v4.0' for .NET 4.6 and 'v3.0' for .NET 3.5.

Look at the [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest)